# Airtable regular expression syntax in a formulae

Tags: regex, airtable

I'm having dificulty extracting the filename from another cell.
The regular expression I have works perfectly on regex101.com but only results in error on airtable.

My working regular expression has a non capturing group followed by everything else:-
`(?:[\\])(.*)`

An example string I'm working with is `Tech Stuff - Old Channels  - image-assets [839605635295772672].csv_Files\IMG_0165-E23DF.JPG`

Does airtable support regular expression groups and if so, what am I doing wrong.

My airtable formulae reads `REGEX_EXTRACT( {Attachments}, '(?:[\\])(.*)')` but results in error
however `REGEX_EXTRACT( {Attachments}, '[A-Za-z]*.[A-Za-z]*')` gets me 'Tech Stuff' no problem but if I try `REGEX_EXTRACT( {Attachments}, '(?>[A-Za-z]*)(.[A-Za-z]*)')`
I just get #ERROR

Comment: What exactly do you want to match or extract in this sample string?

Comment: Everything after the backslash, this far I've not come across multiple backslashes but it's the non capturing group that seems to be giving airtable the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT({Attachments}, '[^\\\\]+\\.[^.]+$')
```

The regex pattern here says to match:

```
[^\\]+  a group on non backslash characters
\.      dot
[^.]+   the file extension
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, wow this is SO close. I have the file extension excluding the . so `png` `JPG` Funny though, because in Regex101.com it does indeed match the whole filename exclusivly.

Comment: This works in Regex101 but not in airtable. `REGEX_EXTRACT({Attachments}, '[^\\]+\.[^.]+$')` only gets me the file extension and not the full filename including extension.

Comment: It isn't possible for my pattern to just give you the extension.  Based on your input above (and from my demo), can you let me know exactly what this current pattern is matching?

Comment: Matches `JPG` only

Comment: Please try this pattern: `[^\\\\]+\\.[^.]+$` ... or maybe `[^\\]+\\.[^.]+$` ... I think the issue here might be that backslash needs to be doubled everywhere

Comment: Yes, you are correct; they do. This works `[^\\\\]+\\.[^.]+$` thanks so much!
If I type a single slash in airtable, it always seems to auto escape it automatically, rather annoying but yes, this was the issue.